# How do I set up a named virtual host on ubuntu with proxy pass?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm running the latest version of ubuntu, 12.04.

I'm trying to access my ruby on rails app via a faux domain, as specified in my /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.vhost
127.0.0.1 www.myapp.vhost
```

and as far as apache goes, I've added my virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.vhost
    ServerAlias *.myapp.vhost
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

to the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf

and in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, I've added

```
Include sites-available/
Include sites-available/myapp.conf
```

to the bottom of the file.

I can restart apache, fin without error using this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

The problem is that when I navigate to http://myapp.vhost in my browser, I get a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: My ruby on rails server is running on port 3001, with the -p3001 option of script/server

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "Include sites-available/myapp.conf" line from /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and rename /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf to be /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp (i.e. remove the '.conf' suffix).

Then issue **sudo a2ensite myapp** and then **sudo service apache2 restart**.

That should get you working.

You may also want to change your *ServerAlias *.myapp.vhost* line to be *ServerAlias www.myapp.vhost* and then try connecting to http://www.myapp.vhost since that is the entry in your /etc/hosts and not just the domain name.

Comment: ok, just did all that, but browser gets 500 error, and the apache error log says `[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /favicon.ico. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
`

Comment: Did you run "sudo a2enmod proxy_http" (sans quotes) and restart apache?